# RSA Encryption with Private key and Decryption with public Key C#

Tags: c#, rsa, private-key, public-key

I am using RSA encryption algorithm. Encryption with public key and decryption with private key is fine. But Encryption with private key and decryption with public key is not working.

```
 private string DecryptWithPublicKey(string encryptedString, string publicKey)
    {

        byte[] textBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);

        var keyLengthBits = 2048;  // need to know length of public key in advance!
        byte[] exponent = new byte[3];
        byte[] modulus = new byte[keyLengthBits / 8];
        Array.Copy(publicKeyBytes, publicKeyBytes.Length - exponent.Length, exponent, 0, exponent.Length);
        Array.Copy(publicKeyBytes, publicKeyBytes.Length - exponent.Length - 2 - modulus.Length, modulus, 0, modulus.Length);

        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
        rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
        rsaKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent; 
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);

        byte[] encrypted = rsa.Decrypt(textBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
```

I am using this method to decrypt. But receiving key not found error.
Is public key decryption possible?

Comment: There is no encryption with the private key and decryption with the public key, only signing and verification. .NET has dedicated methods for this.

Comment: You can only encrypt and decrypt when the keys are the same.  With encryption algorithms usually private keys remain constant and public keys change for every message.  But the public key HAS to be the same for the encryption and decryption.